# issue in appcompatActivity while importing eclispe project android studio

Tags: android, android-support-library, android-appcompat

I am also getting same issue with following appcompat version:

```
compile `com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1`
```

Even i have tried with invalidate still coming same issue.

And same issue for `ViewPager`.

```
compileSdkVersion 21
buildToolsVersion "23.1.1"
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this version of Appcompat

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.0'
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using the support libraries **v23**, you have to compile with api **23.**

```
compileSdkVersion 23
```